# Trouble finding eigenvector for corresponding eigenvalue -1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix of coefficients that is:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        1 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I find the eigenvalues to be -1 and 1.

Eigenvalue 1 gives an eigenvector of

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

but I'm having trouble finding the eigenvector for the corresponding eigenvalue -1, where I seem to get

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Wolfram Alpha is saying it should be

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Any ideas on how it found that?

Thank you.

EDIT - the eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue of 1 was the wrong way round.

Comment: If you show your work leading up to $(0,0)$ we might be able to help you.

Comment: Just use the definition of eigenvalue and write down the equation system you are supposed to solve if $\lambda =-1$.

Comment: And, by the way, $[{}^1_2]$ is not an eigenvector; multiplied by the matrix it gives $[{}^{\;1}_{-1}]$. So perhaps you should also show how you got _that_.

Comment: The second column of the matrix is $-1\cdot(0,1)^T$, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to solve the equation:

$Av = -v$

Where $A$ is your matrix and $v$ is the eigenvector you're looking for.  So (using $x$ for the first coordinate and $y$ for the second):

$1x + 0y = -x$

$1x - 1y = -y$

From the first expression we have that $x = 0$.  So:

$-y = -y$

That's a tautology, so any $y$ will satisfy the equation.  So we may as well pick the normalized one, which has $y = 1$.

As an aside, the $0$ vector will always satisfy the eigenvalue equation, but it's excluded from the definition of eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you, the idea that any y will satisfy the equation was what I found online, but I never came across that before so was unsure if it was valid to write.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The matrix
$$
A= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has characteristic function 
$$
p(\lambda) = \lambda^{2} - 1
$$
whose roots are the eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm} = \pm 1$.

For the eigenvalue $\lambda_{-} =-1$,
$$
A v_{-} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 0 \\
 -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
-
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\lambda_{-} v_{-}
$$